# Fast conversion of Pandas DataFrame to key->row presentation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need a key, row index for my Pandas DataFrame where `key` is the id column of Pandas DataFrame and `data` is the row data.

The data is sparse - I only need to access data for a few keys, but I do not know ahead of time which keys I need to access.

I am currently doing this using `iterrows` as:

```py
pair_map = {}
for pair_id, data in df.iterrows():
     pair_map[pair_id] = data
```

However, for a very large number of rows (~100k-1M), this becomes slow. Would there be any faster ways to create sparse key-row indexes for Pandas, so that access to any row arbitrarily would be fast? Even better if the index is sparse and the data pulled out from Pandas on-demand (though I do not think this is possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
df.T.to_dict()
```

I don't know if you can `transpose` a df with 1M columns and if you re looking for a `dict` with values with type `pd.Series` it is not a the solution

Comment: Works like a charm and feels like ~100x faster!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want a dict with "ID" as key and row values as a list values:

```
pair_map = df.set_index("ID").transpose().to_dict("list")
```